# Append is not working in Drupal

Tags: jquery, drupal-7

I want to add two button after table in drupal. I use table id and append but it is not working. I don't know what is the problem and no error is showing in console.

Here is code . Please help

```
(function($){
  $('#edit-submitted-new-table-element').appendTo('<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="addmorebtn form-submit">Add More</a> <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hidebtn form-submit">Hide it</a>');
$('.hidebtn').css('display', 'none');
alert('h1');
var numcount = 0;
$('#edit-submitted-new-table-element .addmorebtn').live('click', function(){
numcount++;
if(numcount >0 && numcount < 2){
    $('#edit-submitted-new-table-element tr:nth-last-child(2)').css('display', ' table-row');
}
else if(numcount >1 && numcount < 3){
    $('#edit-submitted-new-table-element tr:last-child()').css('display', ' table-row');
    $('.addmorebtn').css('display', 'none');
    $('.hidebtn').removeAttr('style');
    $('.hidebtn').css('display', 'inlne-block');
}

});
$('#edit-submitted-new-table-element .hidebtn').live('click', function(){

if(numcount >= 2 && numcount < 3){
    $('#edit-submitted-new-table-element tr:last-child().odd').removeAttr('style');
}
else if(numcount >=1 && numcount < 2){
    $('#edit-submitted-new-table-element tr:nth-last-child(2).even').removeAttr('style');
    $('.hidebtn').css('display', 'none');
    $('.addmorebtn').removeAttr('style');
     $('.addmorebtn').css('display', 'inline-block');
}
numcount--;
});

}(jQuery));

I want to add two button after table in drupal. I use table id and append but it is not working...
I don't know what is the problem and no error is showing in console.
Here is code . Please help
```

Comment: try to change `$('#edit-submitted-new-table-element').appendTo(` to `$('#edit-submitted-new-table-element').append(`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `appendTo`, instead of `append` to introduce your code. Change it:

```
$('#edit-submitted-new-table-element').append(...)
```

Also you have to change the selectors you are using. For example `last-child()` is incorrect. Change it for this:

```
$('#edit-submitted-new-table-element tr:last-child')...
$('#edit-submitted-new-table-element tr.odd:last-child').removeAttr('style');
$('#edit-submitted-new-table-element tr.even:nth-last-child').removeAttr('style');
```

Hope it helps.